# How to sent mail from nestjs using nodemailer?

Tags: nestjs, sendmail, nodemailer

I am trying to send mail using nodemailer in nestjs from my personal gmail, but receive nothing as result(expecting to get mail in inbox).
Below I attached my code:

```
 `app.module.ts`

 
 @Module({
     imports: [
         MulterModule.register({
         dest: "./uploads"
     }),
         MailerModule.forRoot({
             transport: {
                 host: 'smtp.googlemail.com',
                 port: 465,
                 ignoreTLS: true,
                 secure: true,
                 auth: {
                     user: process.env.EMAIL_ID,
                     pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS
                 },
             },
             defaults: {
                 from: '"No Reply" <no-reply@gmail.com>',
             },
             preview: false,
             template: {
                 dir: process.cwd() + '/template/',
                 adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter(),
                 options: {
                     strict: true,
                 },
             },
         }),
     ],
     controllers: [AppController],
     providers: [AppService]
 
 })
 
 export class AppModule {}
 
 `app.controller.ts`
 
 @Controller()
 export class AppController {
     constructor(private appservice: AppService) {}
 
  @Get()
     sendMail(): void {
        return this.appservice.sendMail()
     }
 }
 
 
 `app.service.ts`
 
 @Injectable()
 export class AppService {
     constructor(private readonly mailerService: MailerService) {}
 
       sendMail(): void {
         this.mailerService.sendMail({
             to: 'leon.wolflans11@gmail.com',
             from: 'leon.wolflans11@gmail.com',
             subject: 'Testing Nest MailerModule ✔', 
             text: 'welcome', 
             html: '<b>welcome</b>',
 
         });
     }
```

When I'm checking this code in postman - I received 200 status code, but when checking my inbox - don't find new mail there.

Comment: Did you turned on **Allow less secure apps** on [https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) ?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to turn on access for less secure app if you are using gmail as your smtp host

use this link [less secure app](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1&rapt=AEjHL4PdRUbgmpkxirVB312CSwmTT2xgFcwr0lLG_nRoHk6ZcH5DmRRu3QCx4nVESWnUosTWopKjM5cuGk_X9QJXmCRa9tDm2Q)

Also your transport configuration should look like this

```
 transport: {
             host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
             port: 465,
             ignoreTLS: true,
             secure: true,
             auth: {
                 user: process.env.EMAIL_ID,
                 pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS
             },
         }
```

smtp.gmail.com works fine for me